# Mix of line and scatter in plotly chart

Tags: python, plotly

Using this code:

```
trace = go.Scatter(x=[1,2,3],
                    y=[1,2,3],
                    name = "chart1",
                    mode="markers+text",
                    opacity = 1)

layout = dict(width=800,
    height=600,autosize=True,margin=dict(
        l=50,
        r=50,
        b=100,
        t=100,
        pad=4
    ))

iplot(dict(data=[trace], layout=layout))
```

Renders:

[image]

How to include in this chart a line that contains values y values `[3,1,4]` for the corresponding x values [`1,2,3]` ?

This code:

```
# libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Data
df=pd.DataFrame({'x': range(1,11), 'y1': np.random.randn(10), 'y2': np.random.randn(10)+range(1,11), 'y3': np.random.randn(10)+range(11,21) })

plt.plot(('x', 'y1'), data=df, marker='o', markerfacecolor='blue', markersize=12, color='skyblue', linewidth=4)
plt.plot(('x', 'y2'), data=df, marker='o', markerfacecolor='blue', markersize=12, color='skyblue', linewidth=4)
plt.plot(('x', 'y3'), data=df, marker='o', markerfacecolor='blue', markersize=12, color='skyblue', linewidth=4, linestyle='dashed', label="toto")

plt.legend()
```

Achieves something similar but is missing the plotly styling:

[image]

I also tried including the y value in the creation of the scatter trace:

```
y=[[1,2,3] , [3,1,4]]
```

But the chart is not rendered as expected :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another trace:

```
trace = go.Scatter(...)  # your original trace
trace2 = go.Scatter(x=[1,2,3], y=[3,1,4], name='chart2')

layout = ...

iplot(dict(data=[trace, trace2], layout=layout))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this too:

```
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_Trace(your trace)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1,2,3], y=[3,1,4],
                mode='lines',
                name='lines'))
fig.add_layout(dict(width=800,
    height=600,autosize=True,margin=dict(
        l=50,r=50,b=100,t=100, pad=4))
fig.show()
```